# Abelian group $G$ such that $pG=p^2G$ for a fixed prime $p$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I know that an abelian group $G$ such that $pG=p^2G$ is of the form $G=D(G)\oplus X$, where
$D(G)$ is the maximal divisible subgroup of $G$, $D(X)=0$, $X/T(X)$ is divisible and $pX_p=0$, where $X_p =\{a \in X : p^na=0 \ \text{for some natural} \  n\}$. Does anyone know where I can find additional know of such groups. I am particularly interested in where I can find the structural theorem fos such groups. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean when you write that way. Please do use LaTeX for mathematics in this site Directions in the FAQ section.

Comment: Standard references are the books on (infinite) abelian groups by Kaplansky or by Fuchs.